# Colorbar for Barplot with negative values

Tags: python, bar-chart, colorbar

I tried to plot some data as a barplot where the color of each bar is defined by its hight. I saw some other questions and answers here and used those ideas. The problem is not, that i can´t create the colorbar, but the color in the plot does not match with the colorbar as you can see in the picture below. So the colorbar is (i think) correct, but the color scheme is not. Every bar below zero is in the same color - that is not supposed to happen.

So my question now is: **Where is my mistake?**

Google couldn´t help me so I hope someone here can.

I used the following (a bit simplified*) code:

```
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [130,35] # setting plot size to large scales so data is shown better
x = np.arange(0,320,1) # recreating a simplified verion of the original data set
#print("x: ",x)
data = [6.82, 5.47, 1.9, 5.83, 6.41, 2.32, 5.6, 5.49, 11.17, 1.0, 6.1, 6.6, 9.49, 1.84, -5.52, -1.41, 9.62, 1.22, 2.26, 5.56, 7.22, 0.41, -1.78, -5.46, 8.31, 4.67, 5.81, 4.23, 7.74, 5.24, 5.34, 7.0, 7.54, 6.1, 2.96, 7.09, 7.62, 0.74, 4.14, 4.81, 9.88, 6.47, 3.25, 3.62, 3.76, 2.48, 2.36, 3.5, 9.14, 6.13, 0.38, -0.39, 8.11, 6.67, 1.15, 1.49, 7.88, 6.14, 3.27, -5.42, 6.3, 5.45, 4.39, 7.09, 7.46, 3.32, 3.34, 5.37, 6.23, 5.71, 3.7, 3.64, 6.99, 4.82, 3.38, 3.82, 9.47, 3.38, 2.19, 8.94, 6.76, 2.71, 5.19, 3.78, 6.21, 0.33, -4.7, -2.59, 10.89, -0.06, 0.83, 4.28, 7.34, 3.58, 3.91, 2.1, 3.68, 5.3, 0.47, 4.86, 5.4, 5.07, 4.65, 7.06, 7.53, 3.86, 2.35, 3.49, 6.94, 0.69, 4.79, 1.19, 9.04, -1.65, -0.09, 1.94, 10.19, 3.86, 3.66, 5.52, 7.05, 6.99, -0.06, 5.53, 7.82, 5.25, 4.02, 4.72, 7.41, 3.97, 7.08, 7.2, 8.89, 8.29, 8.67, 6.43, 7.11, 4.87, 4.61, 3.86, 8.49, 2.61, 3.83, 7.3, 8.76, 5.59, 4.35, 2.34, 8.5, 2.84, -1.48, -0.49, 7.56, 6.98, 0.69, 5.76, 6.32, 4.58, 2.79, 3.02, 8.4, -0.3, 2.5, 4.17, 9.82, 4.94, 7.57, 2.41, 8.27, 4.95, 4.44, 3.22, 8.82, 4.05, -2.39, 1.57, 3.87, 7.47, 3.04, -2.96, 10.71, 5.59, -3.25, 3.43, 8.09, 5.19, 7.37, 5.94, 6.94, 6.48, 6.76, 8.47, 7.18, 6.14, 6.81, 10.95, 7.71, 4.08, 5.25, 1.39, 7.34, 4.8, 3.94, 7.37, 8.96, 4.38, 6.22, 2.17, 3.12, 6.18, 6.37, 2.4, 10.6, 7.18, 3.8, 8.47, 7.22, 0.21, -0.85, 0.61, 7.32, 0.78, 0.7, 8.59, 7.07, 5.07, 6.45, 9.01, 4.64, 4.75, 6.97, 4.2, 7.8, 5.95, 5.3, 7.92, 10.41, 6.3, 4.06, 6.31, 8.03, 3.34, 5.56, 9.36, 8.44, 1.69, 3.54, 2.68, 10.27, 6.0, 3.85, 6.76, 8.17, 5.08, 6.19, 3.11, 8.31, 4.63, 1.59, 3.1, 11.31, 8.46, 8.35, 7.19, 7.67, 4.69, 7.34, 8.43, 8.14, 3.81, 2.3, 4.39, 11.42, 3.32, -1.41, 2.7, 7.12, -1.46, 4.54, 4.59, 8.52, 7.63, 5.06, 2.36, 8.89, 5.33, 2.72, 2.59, 8.26, 7.97, 5.08, 9.35, 9.98, 5.58, 5.37, 5.42, 11.86, 11.21, 4.03, 7.02, 7.41, 6.99, 2.3, 6.24, 8.69, 6.19, 6.62, 2.29, 9.11, 7.22, 4.24, 10.04, 8.37, 7.59, 7.72, 8.98, 10.96, 6.81, 3.73, 5.94]

data_hight_normalized = [i/max(data) for i in data] # copied from some other question
my_cmap = plt.cm.get_cmap("plasma")
colors = my_cmap(data_hight_normalized) # i think the mistake is somewhere around here

sm = ScalarMappable(cmap=my_cmap, norm=plt.Normalize(min(data)-1,max(data)+1))
sm.set_array([])
cbar = plt.colorbar(sm,extend="both")
cbar.set_label('Scale', rotation=270,labelpad=100,fontsize=70)
cbar.ax.tick_params(labelsize=40)

plt.bar(x,data,color=colors)

plt.xticks(range(0,int(max(x)),1),fontsize=8)

plt.yticks(range(int(min(data))-1,int(max(data))+2,1),fontsize=40)

plt.grid(axis="y",linewidth=2)
plt.grid(axis="x",linewidth=1)
plt.xlabel("X", fontsize = 70)
plt.ylabel("Y",fontsize = 70)
plt.title("Colorbar",fontsize= 80)
plt.show()
```

That gives the following plot:
[image]

*The major changes are the label names and that the original data is extracted from a txt file

Comment: I dont know if the plot is wrong... If you look at the colorbar, anything below 2.5 is the dark blue and then moves to kind of purple and so on

Comment: as far as i would interpret it, every negative bar has the same color. But I don´t really know what you mean.